# Login to SQL Azure using Windows Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to have domain joined SQL Azure servers or Database so that we can use logins from our Active directory using windows Authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly SQL Azure currently does not support Windows Authentication right now (i.e: integrated security) and it only supports SQL Authentication where user should provide username and password all the time.

For more info on SQL Azure security guide lines take a look at the link below:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-security-guidelines/

But if you are willing to use the preview, Microsoft has announced support for Azure Active Directory login support for Azure SQL Databases:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/preview-azure-ad-authentication-7/

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft announced support for AAD auth for Azure SQL DB recently. Check out details on the doc page and the blog post below.

[https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsecurity/archive/2015/09/16/azure-active-directory-authentication-is-in-public-preview.aspx)

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsecurity/archive/2015/09/16/azure-active-directory-authentication-is-in-public-preview.aspx](http://[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsecurity/archive/2015/09/16/azure-active-directory-authentication-is-in-public-preview.aspx][1])

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/preview-azure-ad-authentication-7/

Answer (score 5):

Recently Microsoft announced support for Azure Active Directory login support for Azure SQL Databases in public preview. You can read the blog post announcing this feature here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/preview-azure-ad-authentication-7/ and the documentation here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/.