# Deploying java application on linux with connection to Azure SQL Server via Active Directory

Tags: java, linux, azure, active-directory, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to deploying java application on Linux machine which uses Azure SQL database as datastore.

With SQL Authentication method for DB connection, I was able to successfully deploy the app.

However, one of the requirement of the project is to uses Active directory to support Active Directory Authentication for DB connection.

So what I'm trying to do is basically, deploying and running the application on linux machine(ubuntu) with connection to Azure SQL Database through Active Directory Authentication rather than SQL authentication, which authenticate DB user via Active directory.

I'm pretty sure it will work if we deploying the app on window machine, but challenge part is to use linux machine as application server.

I have tried to find any good references on the web but couldn't find which satisfies my requirement.

So I'm not sure if it is even possible to achieve the goal. if so, could anyone provide any good references??

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> one of the requirement of the project is to uses Active directory
> to support Window authentication for DB connection.

Based on my understanding, you use Azure SQL database(Paas), unfortunately, now, Azure SQL does not support Windows Authentication. Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661205/login-to-sql-azure-using-windows-authentication).

On your scenario, you could use [`Active Directory integrated authentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication).

You could add an Azure Active Directory user/group as an Azure SQL Administrator. Then you could use this user/group to login your SQL with AD Authentication.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused with window authentication with AD authentication. The requirement is actually to use AD authentication. I was able to configure Azure AD with Azure SQL Database and create user/group. but keep failing to deploying the app on linux with connection to SQL Server through AD authentication.....

Comment: @androisojavaswift Hi, Azure AD authentication only works on Windows OS, please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication#azure-ad-features-and-limitations). `Azure AD authentication is supported by the .NET Framework Data Provider for SqlServer; at least version .NET Framework 4.6`

Comment: @androisojavaswift currently, .Net Framework 4.6 is not supported on Linux.